# ¿Cómo coloco mi bloque If en Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, condiciones

espero que se encuentren bien. Cree una macro que trabaja con una celda y cuatro valores: Ashi, Jack, Planetina y Morty, los cuales están distribuidos en dos parejas como lo muestro abajo. Yo quiero que la celda valga uno si, por lo menos, hay un miembro de cada pareja que vale uno (Ej, si Morty y Ashi valen uno, o Jack y Planetina) y que valga cero en caso contrario (Ej, si solo Jack y Ashi valen 1, o solo Morty).

Al construir mi bloque If, me percato de que hace que la celda valga uno cuando Ashi es igual a 1 y los demás 0, cuando tendría que hacerlo sólo si también Morty o Planetina son 1. Necesitaría saber cómo ordenar los conectores Or y And para que me funcionen correctamente. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
Sub Prueba()

Dim Ashi, Jack, Planetina, Morty As Byte
Dim Celda As Range

Set Celda = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")

'PAREJA 1
Ashi = 1
Jack = 0

'PAREJA 2
Planetina = 0
Morty = 0

If Ashi = 1 Or Jack = 1 And Planetina = 1 Or Morty = 1 Then
    Celda.Value = 1
Else
    Celda.Value = 0
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dos cosas: 1) Cuando haces `Dim Ashi, Jack, Planetina, Morty As Byte` solo declaras como Byte Morty, las demás son tipo variant. Especifica SIEMPRE el tipo de variable. 2) Mirate SELECT CASE, creo que puede ayudarte en tu lógica mejor que IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver, no entiendo muy bien tu planteamiento, porque por lo que dices, lo que buscas es que si hay un valor de 1 en cualquiera de las 4 variables, la celda A1 deberá de tener el valor 1, aquí la diferenciación para parejas sería insignificante, pues estas pidiendo lo mismo.

En tu in, lo que evalúas es que si en la primera pareja hay un 1, y en la segunda pareja hay otro 1, que te ponga 1. O sea, que para darte ese uno, tendrían que tener obligatoriamente un 1 tanto la primera como la segunda pareja

En tu caso simplemente cambiarías ese AND por un OR, y pasaría a indicar que si en cualquiera de las cuatro variables tienes un valor de 1, que te ponga uno en la celda

Si lo que deseas es separar los condicionales por parejas, puedes usar un if para cada pareja, te pongo un ejemplo empleando dos variables booleanas que evalúan si en la pareja hay un 1, si lo hay ésta variable coge el valor de true

luego puedes jugar con esos variables booleanas en otros if

```
Sub Prueba()

    Dim Ashi, Jack, Planetina, Morty As Byte
    Dim Celda As Range
    Dim pareja1, pareja2 As Boolean

    Set Celda = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")

    'variables de PAREJA 1 para el ejemplo cogen los valores de las celdas B1 y B2
    Ashi = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B1").Value
    Jack = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B2").Value

    'variables de PAREJA 2 para el ejemplo cogen los valores de las celdas B3 y B4
    Planetina = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B3").Value
    Morty = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B4").Value

    'si en la primera pareja hay un valor de 1
    If ((Ashi = 1) Or (Jack = 1)) Then
        'variable booleana a true
        pareja1 = True
    End If

    'si en la segunda pareja hay un 1
    If ((Planetina = 1) Or (Morty = 1)) Then
        'variable booleana a true
        pareja2 = True
    End If

    'si la variable está a true
    If pareja1 = True Then
        'pone 1 en la celda
        Celda.Value = 1
    End If

    'si la variable booleana está a true
    If pareja2 = True Then
        ¡pone 1 a la celda
        Celda.Value = 1
    End If

End Sub
```